# a more extensive library of math functions for CUDA kernel? particularly incomplete beta

Tags: cuda

I know about the cuda math library, and the cuda 4.1 toolkit version has good stuff like the gamma and bessel functions. I need the regularized incomplete beta function (a.k.a the cumulative distribution function for the beta probability distribution). Is this available in any open source library?

Comment: I think most modern computer implementations are based on [this](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?doid=131766.131776).

Comment: @talonmies Thanks for the reference, i hope i don't have to implement that myself ;)

Comment: A followup to the paper referenced by talonmies is: Barry W. Brown and Lawrence B. Levy, Certification of Algorithm 708: significant-digit computation of the incomplete beta, ACM Transactions on Mathematical Software, Volume 20 Issue 3, Sept. 1994

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know enough about statistical functions, but it looks like the function incbet() in the Cephes library may be a reasonable starting point. The Cephes library has an excellent reputation, and sources are readily available via Netlib. See http://www.netlib.org/cephes

Inside the archive cprob.tgz there is a file incbet.c which contains the source for incbet().

Comment: I've also discovered that the Gnu scientific library has the special function I'm looking for. I was hoping to find a specifically CUDA library, but I suppose this (or Cephes) will do the trick.

Comment: It probably wouldn't hurt to file a bug with a feature request with NVIDIA (via the registered developer website).