# beta pdf function for CUDA

Tags: cuda, statistics

I need something like `betapdf(x,a,b)` ([**Beta probability density function**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution)) function in CUDA? Is there this function for CUDA or I should implement it myself?

Comment: Same as [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9659453/a-more-extensive-library-of-math-functions-for-cuda-kernel-particularly-incompl) question?

Comment: @GeorgeAprilis incomplete beta function is different from betapdf like OP is asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a function that you can use on both host and device. On the host you will need to include math.h.

```
__host__ __device__ 
double betapdf(double x, double a, double b)
{
   //if (x < 0 || x > 1) return 0;
   double tmp = pow((1 - x), (b - 1)) * pow(x, (a - 1));
   double iB = tgamma(a + b) / (tgamma(a) * tgamma(b));  // 1/B
   return tmp * iB;
}
```

Uncomment the first line if you **do not know** x is going to lie in [0 1].

**EDIT**: In case you are using float, use `powf` and `tgammaf` instead.

**EDIT 2** Like @njuffa mentioned in the comments, this particular code may suffer from intermediate overflow problems. In which case the following method may be better.

```
__host__ __device__ 
double betapdf2(double x, double a, double b)
{
   //if (x < 0 || x > 1) return 0;
   double tmp = pow((1 - x), (b - 1)) * pow(x, (a - 1));
   double iB = exp(lgamma(a + b) - lgamma(a) - lgamma(b)); // 1/B
   return tmp * iB;
}
```

Comment: Depending on the range of `a` and `b` the computation of the beta function `beta(a,b) = tgamma(a) * tgamma(b) / tgamma(a+b)` may suffer from intermediate overflow, even though the final result is representable. In that case, you can use `beta(a,b) = exp (lgamma(a) + lgamma(b) - lgamma(a+b))` instead.

Comment: @njuffa Thanks I will be adding it in!

Comment: Statistical functions are outside my area of expertise, but are you sure the code should be multiplying by the beta function rather than dividing by it? The formula I am looking at says: betapdf(x,a,b) = x**(a-1) * (1-x)**(b-1) / beta(a,b). I don't know which version is correct. Could you double check?

Comment: @njuffa Oops. You are right there. I was in a hurry in the morning and   missed that bit.

Answer (score 2):

Well I don't know about beta functions, but there are two variant of gamma functions in CUDA, see: [CUDA Math API](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-math-api/index.html) for more details.

Comment: Does this have anything to do with the question?

Comment: Well yes, they have relationships with each other that allows using the gamma function instead of the beta function. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function#Relationship_between_gamma_function_and_beta_function)

Comment: @SorooshBateni ~> So How can I calculate betapdf(x,a,b) using the function you mentioned ?

Comment: according to the [definition](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/betapdf.html) of the betapdf, You have to replace B(a,b) with (I use G as gamma) : G(a)*G(b)/(G(a+b)

Comment: Well I can't find a publicly available source code of betapdf function in C or C++, If you have one please post it in your question.